Error 422 from Safe API for multi-sig transaction
We're sending the following multi-sig transaction, to Safe API and it returns a 422 error (incorrect parameters). Is it possible to know the error in the transaction payload (without the data field)? There isn't much documentation on the site that was of help.
The transaction payload was created with parameters from createTransaction() function in the SDK.
{
  safe: '0x7011b0CaaFc2F51Cbe767Cdf215796b94AB33924',
  to: '0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff',
  data: '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',
  value: '0',
  operation: 0,
  gasToken: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  safeTxGas: '0',
  baseGas: '0',
  gasPrice: '0',
  refundReceiver: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  nonce: 2,
  contractTransactionHash: '0x76e103cd61bf60e03ce9638f5c967f2344fbadadb7f478fd6b7f1c8ba038139f',
  sender: '0x0c381Abb94605d96C00B4B9702e8C251c1897cD8',
  signature: '0x2198b1d82aa42d0864cc91b46656ce8a49204f525681042d5167c2e700943044377e83adec99bd92175a7db17cafded8c0db18803772e8bd1fb75a08e139c4c420',
  origin: ''
}

I'm using the polygon API
https://safe-transaction-polygon.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0x7011b0CaaFc2F51Cbe767Cdf215796b94AB33924/multisig-transactions/


It looks like the to address is not checksummed. You can use a service like ethsum.netlify.app to checksum and then try to execute the transaction again.
Please let me know if it solved the problem!
Best, Louis

It worked. Thanks so much.

Glad to hear that! Feel free to mark the question as solved if you have no further issues
